# Looking for the best solution to build this Blog structure? Picture attached?

Tags: categories, menus

I'm trying to build a **scalable** structure, let say I want to add different cities and have different categories so my URLs should look like this: (You can check the picture attached)

- website.com/paris/party | website.com/paris/music | website.com/paris/lifestyle
- website.com/london/party | website.com/london/music | website.com/london/lifestyle

So I have:

- 1 dropdown menu for cities
- 1 nav menu for categories such as: Party, Music or Lifestyle

***If there anyone who have a Nice scalable solution for that?***

```
Step by step explanation are better :)
```

I was thinking to build it this way:

- Cities as Main Categories
- Party, Music, Lifestyle... as subcategories for each city

However, each time I want to add a new city, it's not really good because I have to: 
1)

1. Add new Category (ex: London)
2. Add sub-Categories for London: Party, Music, Lifestyle
3. Create a new menu for this city (on the picture: "Popular Tags") and adding here those sub-Categories...

Any way to avoid this repeating process?

***Thanks for any help!***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve what you are talking about within Wordpress.

1) **Multisite/Network**. For each City (or whatever your top level is), you create a new site with a default theme. This allows for either www.website.com/paris/music or paris.website.com/music, depending on your requirements.

[Introductory info on Network sites](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network)

[Creating a Wordpress Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

2) **Write Plugin to automate item creation** You could wrap the category creation and subcategory assignment on a single site, as well as menu creation, into a plugin. From plugin admin you enter new top level categories, and have it do the rest.

[Plugin Development Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/)

A combination of 1 and 2 above is possible as well.

You also approach it with hierarchical **Custom Post Types** and **custom taxonomies**.

[Taxonomies in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

[Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

In either case, theme templates solve the front end display.

Study the [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) for possibilities.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. So if I'm using multisite structure, I will pay the hosting for each subfolders (cities) that I will create right? About the Custom Post Types, You suggest to create 1 Custom Post Type for Each City and add inside Each Custom Taxonomies (which here will be the same for every city)?

Comment: As far as hosting a multisite/network, it is run from a single wordpress core install. You do need some extra things, like dedicated ip and ability to setup wildcard dns if you're going to do subdomains. I do not recommend a shared hosting plan for it. On the other...

Comment: All right, so I'm creating let's say a Network/Multisite and installing WP on "website.com", then I create "website.com/paris" and "website.com/london" as a subfolders and host them. So in this Case I Will pay more for the hosting than using a SingleSite? Could you clarify me also If I'm right concerning Custom Post Types? Thanks again.

Comment: Taxonomies can be shared across post types. So you can have a _music_ Taxonomy and assign it to the  _Paris_ CPT and to the _Berlin_ CPT. Or have a _cities_ CPT with entries of _Paris_, _Berlin_, etc., and a _music_ CPT and tie them together relationally through a shared taxonomy (say _City Name_ with values of each CPT post. On the last one, a city post named Berlin and a Music post about Berlin could both have _Berlin_ taxonomy.  The organizational structure depends on what you wish to achieve.

Comment: You create Network install on Website.com. You choose subdirectory install. From within WP Network Admin, you create a new site named "Paris". This will exist at Website.com/Paris. It will add a site_id layer to the database. All manageable through one install, and possible to have separate admins for each, with a Super Admin user over the Network.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see the benefit of Using WP Multisite here? I mean this website(blog) is not for a client is for me. So I will manage this website directly. I will only have maybe some additional authors (content/post contributors).

Comment: You could very well not need it. Subdomains and a level of separation of concerns with a shared code base would be the benefit, but if that is counter-intuitive to how you will manage it, then yeah I wouldn't approach it that way. Most likely a version of the CPT/Tax method plus some custom functions to generate menus every time you add a new city.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently doing with CPT/Tax. So, I create a CPT for each cities, for now two cities : Paris and London. I create a taxonomy call "Section". There I create also Paris and London and I'm adding: Party Lifestyle and Music as child(section) of Paris and London. They must be child is this correct?

Comment: There are multiple ways to approach it. I would recommend digging into the links regarding Taxonomies and CPTs to fully see all those possibilities, and from there find the method best suited for your desired results. The taxonomies may be best as children, may not. There are potential functional advantages/disadvantages in each case. You're organizing data and its associations and relations to achieve an end goal with that data and those relations, so I'm afraid anything I offer beyond pointing you to those resources above risks conjecturing on my end.